# How to correct a large number of duplicate records

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to correct a large number of duplicate records in SQL Server, is there a way I can do this as a bulk update, rather than running an update script for each row?

The data looks like this:

```
client | voucher_no | sequence_no | id
-------+------------+-------------+------
AA     | 11111111   | 1           | 0001
AA     | 11111111   | 1           | 0002 
AA     | 11111111   | 1           | 0003
AA     | 11111112   | 13          | 0004
AA     | 11111112   | 13          | 0004
AA     | 11111113   | 28          | 0005
AA     | 11111113   | 28          | 0006
AA     | 11111114   | 17          | 0007
AA     | 11111114   | 17          | 0008
AA     | 11111115   | 23          | 0009
AA     | 11111115   | 23          | 0010
```

I am have been trying to find a way to update the records in one go, so that the results of the script would be:

```
client | voucher_no | sequence_no | id
-------+------------+-------------+------
AA     | 11111111   | 1           | 0001
AA     | 11111111   | 2           | 0002 
AA     | 11111111   | 3           | 0003
AA     | 11111112   | 13          | 0004
AA     | 11111112   | 14          | 0005
AA     | 11111113   | 28          | 0006
AA     | 11111113   | 29          | 0007
AA     | 11111114   | 17          | 0008
AA     | 11111114   | 18          | 0009
AA     | 11111115   | 23          | 0010
AA     | 11111115   | 24          | 0011


UPDATE table_a
SET sequence_no = (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sequence_no ORDER BY t.client, t.voucher_no, t.sequence_no ))
                   FROM table_a AS t
                   WHERE t.id IN (0002, 0003, 0005, 0007, 0009, 0011)
```

The above works fine for the first id in the list, but it updates the remaining records with the same sequence_no as the first.

So I end up with:

```
client | voucher_no | sequence_no | id
-------+------------+-------------+------
AA     | 11111111   | 2           | 0002 
AA     | 11111111   | 2           | 0003
AA     | 11111112   | 2           | 0005
AA     | 11111113   | 2           | 0007
AA     | 11111114   | 2           | 0009
AA     | 11111115   | 2           | 0011
```

Which can cause further issues if the sequence number is updated to one that already exists for that client and voucher_no combination.

I have also tried wrapping the above in a cursor, thinking that the query isn't getting the chance to update with the correct sequence_no for the next id number, but that hasn't worked either

Comment: please provide table schema.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the duplicate rows? Are you trying to update all the sequence numbers? Sample data and expected results will really help here.

Comment: try `partition by t.id` and also can you create a [SQLFiddle](www.sqlfiddle.com) for the data?

Comment: Apologies, I will provide further information in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue, by using the following code:

```sql
DECLARE @client VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @voucher_no INT 
DECLARE @sequence_no INT
DECLARE @id INT 


DECLARE cursor_results CURSOR FOR 
WITH T AS 
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY client, voucher_no, sequence_no) AS cnt 
      FROM table_a 
)

  SELECT t.client, t.voucher_no, t.sequence_no,t.id
    FROM T AS t 
   WHERE t.cnt > 1
   AND agrtid IN (0002, 0003, 0005, 0007, 0009, 0011) 
ORDER BY t.client, t.voucher_no, t.sequence_no DESC 

OPEN cursor_results 
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_results INTO @client, @voucher_no, @sequence_no, @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @new_sequence_no INT = (SELECT MAX(sequence_no) + 1 FROM table_a WHERE client = @client AND voucher_no = @voucher_no)
    UPDATE table_a
       SET sequence_no = @new_sequence_no,
           last_update = GETDATE(),
           user_id = 'USR' 
     WHERE id = @id 
       AND client = @client 
       AND voucher_no = @voucher_no

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_results INTO @client, @voucher_no, @sequence_no, @id
END 

CLOSE cursor_results 
DEALLOCATE cursor_results
```

While this probably isn't the best way to approach this problem using the cursor allows me to step through the records and update them individually, before moving onto the next.

Setting @new_sequence_no in this manner also ensured I was getting the correct MAX(sequence_no) + 1 for the record I was on at that time, rather than all of the duplicates being given the MAX(sequence_no) + 1 for the first record.